# SciPy in Python 2.7 and Python 3

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, anaconda

I would like to use a module (that requires scipy) in Python 2.7, but for some reason the Python interpreter tells me that I am missing a scipy.special. I do not know why is this, because such an error did not occur when running the Python 3 interpretor.

I have attempted to install scipy through Anaconda and pip, but neither of those options seemed to help.

Comment: It seems your py-scipy install is broken for your py2-dist. This is always expected (currently) when using pip on windows. Reinstall it with conda, and nothing else (and make sure you are using conda correctly; when py2 is an environment there, activating it and then call conda install scipy)!

Comment: Did you explicitly `import scipy.special`?

Comment: The issue has been resolved. Also, I did not explicitly import. I resolved this by creating a new conda environment.